# mysql query not return expected result

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure.This is genuine question , so don't give negetive.

```
CREATE TABLE `acd_goals` (
  `goals_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pipeline_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `goals_month` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `goals_year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `goals_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `nos_of_opp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`goals_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=508 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Check this fiddle for data. [click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11c15/1).

I want result of month current month and previous 2 month , ex: current month is `Feb-2017` then result will be from `Dec-2016` to `Feb-2017`.

I have tried below query but it is not return right result to me.

```
SELECT * FROM `acd_goals`  
where (goals_month >=DATE_FORMAT('2017-06-01','%c')  and goals_year = DATE_FORMAT('2017-06-01','%y') or (MONTH(NOW())>= goals_month and goals_year =YEAR(NOW())) and user_id =1)
```

my expected result is:

```
goals_id    pipeline_id user_id goals_month goals_year  goals_amount    nos_of_opp  created_by  created_date    modified_date
410 2   1   6   2017    100 2   1   2017-02-09T19:52:46Z    2017-02-09T19:52:46Z
411 2   1   7   2017    200 4   1   2017-02-09T19:52:46Z    2017-02-09T19:52:46Z
412 2   1   8   2017    200 4   1   2017-02-09T19:52:46Z    2017-02-09T19:52:46Z
```

Comment: If you are expecting June through August, then why does your expected result set have all February data?

Comment: i want to get result of cur month and previous 2 month, so when there is `feb-2017` then result will be from `dec-2016` to `feb-2017`

Comment: why negative? is there any wrong with my question?

Comment: Yes, there is.  You never showed any sample data, leaving everyone guessing at the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general strategy of this query is to convert the goal month and year to a bona fide date on the first of the month using `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(goals_year, '-', goals_month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then, retain the rows you want where the goal date is within the 2 month range you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM acd_goals
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(goals_year, '-', goals_month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') >=
    DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(goals_year, '-', goals_month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') <=
DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')
```

Comment: it gives me result upto month `12`

Comment: You never showed us any sample data and this is the best I can do.  See if you can get my query working for you.

Comment: there is a sample data in sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e11c15/1 , i also add this fiddle in question

Comment: @chiragsatapara Hence the importance of giving us sample data when you post a question.

Comment: there is so much data, that why i create a sqlfiddle , instead of give data in to the question , Thanks tim for your answer

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
SELECT * FROM `acd_goals`  
WHERE goals_month BETWEEN 6 AND 8
```

Comment: what about year?

Comment: add at the end AND goals_year = 2017 or as you writted AND goals_year = YEAR(NOW())

Comment: WHERE (goals_month BETWEEN MONTH(NOW()) - 2 AND MONTH(NOW())) AND goals_year = YEAR(NOW())

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM `acd_goals` Where
   DATE(MAKEDATE(goals_year, 1) + interval (goals_month - 1) month) 
    Between Date(NOW() - interval 2 month - interval day(now()) day)
    And NOW()

   AND user_id = 1
```